Why do web browsers seem to have 30% CPU usage on new tab from mouse movements?
I can reproduce this by swishing the cursor back and forth on a new tab. Extensions are disabled. The CPU usage is unnecessarily high for other things (+70% CPU usage when loading a client side rendering (CSR) app). Parts of the screen also go black when youtube is playing.
Doesn't matter if it is a chrome based browser or Firefox.
30% seems to be the maximum CPU usage of a single thread for my CPU.
I am running this on an Intel i5-4590 on Windows 11 which doesn't support the CPU.
It feels like I have crypto mining malware. Other apps are do not have this problem.

My money's on "normal web app inefficiency".

Anecdotally, on this 10-year-old laptop, I get no more than a jump from ~4% to 7% with violent mouse twitching. Try running from USB, e.g., Hiren's BootCD PE (https://www.hirensbootcd.org), opening an included web browser, and see how CPU usage is.

Turns out I had set my refresh rate to 360 Hz then forgotten to turn it back to 60 Hz.
Strange how it affected web browsers but not other apps.
